# How to Call 2 awaitable tasks on single button onclick in blazor

Tags: html, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a button to take the picture in a razor file. I used the code below

```
 <button class="btn" type="button" @onclick="CapturePhotoAsync"></button>
```

in razor.cs file

```
 private async Task CapturePhotoAsync()
{
    if (cameraModuleRef != null)
    {
        isLoading = true;
        StateHasChanged();

        await cameraModuleRef.InvokeVoidAsync("capturePhoto", ...);
        {
            var photo = ObjectSpace.CreateObject<Photo>();
           ...
        }
           ..
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a sound to it
I know the steps for adding the sound.

```
   private async Task Play()
                            {
                                await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("PlayShutter", "shutter");
                            }
```

It works if I call this task from a seperate button. But how can I call both tasks from the same button onclick event?
I am using Xaf blazor application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private async Task CapturePhotoAsync()
{
    if (cameraModuleRef != null)
    {
        isLoading = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    //  await cameraModuleRef.InvokeVoidAsync("capturePhoto", ...);
        var task1 = cameraModuleRef.InvokeVoidAsync("capturePhoto", ...);
        var task2 = Play();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

        var photo = ObjectSpace.CreateObject<Photo>();
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to blazor. I don't understand how to add this to the button's "OnClick" event. Please explain your answer.

Comment: Well, you started with `...`. But edited.

Comment: Thank you. It works in all browsers except Safari. Can anyone tell me why iOS is not supporting it?  How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I wonder why this code is not working in safari. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: First of all, describe "not working". As a question that isn't much to go on.

Comment: I mean while capturing the picture, the sound is not coming in safari. But it comes in other browsers..

Comment: Try starting task2 first. If that doesn't work, post a new question with the safari tag. Best is a [mre] , try replacing the camera stuff with a Task.Delay(100);

Comment: Task.Delay(100) didn't help it. Created a new question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75576137/audio-not-playing-while-taking-the-picture-in-safari-blazor-project-used-javas